# Visualize IP data on map

Tags: geoip

I have been using a honeypot and collecting some IPs of attackers. Now I am using geolite2/python to get the location of the attackers. 
My question is, are there any tools to visualize the locations of the attackers on a world map?

Comment: ***Use a geolocation service: http://www.iplocation.net/***.

Comment: @cybermonkey Could you be more specific? I can find the **name** of the location, but don't know how to **put that on a world map**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Google's Data Visualization tools, specifically, the geo chart tools.

found in here: 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

You can prepare the data in Json format and load it to Javascript, then send google the data and you will have a map gernated by google.

Comment: Nice tool. I can prepare the map IP -> Country using a GeoIP tool, then put that data to "Region Geocharts"

Answer (score 4):

You can do this via IPInfo's free [Map IPs](http://ipinfo.io/map) tool, which creates an interactive map of IP addresses. For eg: check this map of [AWS IP Ranges](https://ipinfo.io/map/7c9e3031-ff5a-4769-bdd2-3506831d63a0).

[image: map ips tool preview]

You can either copy/paste the IPs or use the tool via cURL. It will process up to 500K IPs.

```sh
$ cat ipList | curl -XPOST --data-binary @- "ipinfo.io/map?cli=1"
```

**Disclaimer**: I work at IPInfo.

Answer (score 0):

The GeoIP data can be visuallized with Splunk (http://www.splunk.com/) and its Google Maps add-on (https://apps.splunk.com/app/368/). This add-on has a GeoIP component already, so an external GeoIP program is not needed.